# Does Rust track unique object ids and can we print them?

Tags: rust, identity

Does Rust use some kind of instance id for each object behind the scenes and if so, can it be made visible?

Consider this

```
struct SomeStruct;

fn main() {
    let some_thing = SomeStruct;
    println!("{:UniqueId}", some_thing);
    let another = some_thing;
    println!("{:UniqueId}", another);
}
```

I'm using a pseudo format string with `{:UniqueId}` here. In this case it may print

```
4711
4712
```

I know that Rust makes a bitwise copy and I want to make that actually visible. If I had such an instance id I could make it visible by comparing ids.

There may be an alternative way to achieve the same though.

Comment: For your example, `SomeStruct` is not `Copy`able, so it would be moved. When something moves, do you want the object ID to be the same or different?

Comment: But a move is also just a bitwise copy with the difference that the old place becomes invalid (ownership moved). So basically I want to make visible that those are really different chunks of memory ;)

Comment: *"But a move is also just a bitwise copy"* not necessarily. In your example, nothing would be copied, because there is nothing **to** copy :-). In general, I believe the compiler is also free to optimize out moves that don't change the program behavior.

Comment: Ok, but can we make it visible somehow? Something like `{:p}` but not limited to pointers. I just love to make all those small things visible rather than just take them for granted ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Rust does not have any automatically generated ID for objects. That kind of functionality would incur some overhead for every user, and Rust wants to impose as little overhead as it needs to. Everything else should be opt-in.

---

As far as I know, the address of an item is as unique as you can get:

```
struct SomeStruct;

fn main() {
    let some_thing = SomeStruct;
    println!("{:p}", &some_thing);
    let another = some_thing;
    println!("{:p}", &another);
}
```

```
0x7ffc020ba638
0x7ffc020ba698
```

Everything<sup>1</sup> takes up space somewhere, so you can get the address of that space and print that.

This might be **too** unique for some cases. For example, when you transfer ownership of an item, you might expect that the ID stays the same. I think in that case, you'd have to roll your own. [Something like a global atomic variable that you can pull from when you create the object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32935808/155423). Such a scheme won't apply to objects you don't control.

---

**1** — Well, almost everything. I know that `const` items aren't guaranteed to have a location, which is why `static` items exist.

Comment: Mmh...ok then. In this example it prints out two different addresses so it did copy. You commented above that it wouldn't copy. I'm confused ;)

Comment: @Christoph my guess is that optimization is coming into play. My psychic powers say you are compiling this locally as `rustc foo.rs`. If so, try adding `-O` ^_^. When I run the code on [the playpen](http://is.gd/yOM8IE), I see two lines of the same value for `-O2` and two different values for `-O0`.

Comment: Notice that on this example both pointers will be the same because those are zero-sized objects! Here's a better view of it http://is.gd/WUQVxN.
So yeah, you should probably add to your '*' that zero sized objects doesn't take space too :)

Comment: @thelink2012 that's what I would have expected too, but try turning off optimization (as mentioned a few comments above). You will see two different values printed! Crazy!

Comment: @Shepmaster wow that one is really interesting! Although if the zero-sized is dynamically allocated they'll have the same allocated address regardless of optimization =P. So I still suggest to add it to the '*' point.

Comment: @thelink2012 well, the footnote indicates items that can't be *referenced*, not items that have no size or that are coalesced into one ^_^. You certainly can get the address of zero-sized items, boxed or not.

Comment: **Warning**: The Rust language makes no guarantee, and the optimizer is therefore free NOT to move (in memory) when it's more efficient. Therefore an observed move in Debug might not occur in Release, and both executions would still be valid.

Comment: It's probably worth noting one can get an idea via addresses by heap-allocating non-zero-sized things with a `Box`. The `Box` pointer itself will then be unique and stable (there's no guarantee of uniqueness for zero-sized things). Alternatively, one can just store an id inside the objects.

Comment: Sorry for digging it up again. The thing I still don't seem to understand. Why does it *not* print the same memory addresses as soon as I make `SomeStruct` to contain a vector?  http://is.gd/Pqd1px Because if I don't have a vector in my struct it does print the same memory addresses: http://is.gd/WUQVxN (assuming it's compiled in release mode for both)