# Generate sequential IDs for each instance of a struct

Tags: rust

I'm writing a system where I have a collection of `Object`s, and each `Object` has a unique integral ID. Here's how I would do it in C++:

```
class Object {
public:
  Object(): id_(nextId_++) { }

private:
  int id_;
  static int nextId_;
}

int Object::nextId_ = 1;
```

This is obviously not thread_safe, but if I wanted it to be, I could make `nextId_` an `std::atomic_int`, or wrap a mutex around the `nextId_++` expression.

How would I do this in (preferably safe) Rust? There's no static struct members, nor are global mutable variables safe. I could always pass `nextId` into the `new` function, but these objects are going to be allocated in a number of places, and I would prefer not to pipe the `nextId` number hither and yon. Thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> nor are global mutable variables safe

Your C++ example seems like it would have thread-safety issues, but I don't know enough C++ to be sure.

However, only *unsynchronized* global mutable variables are trouble. If you don't care about cross-thread issues, you can use a thread-local:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Monster {
    id: usize,
    health: u8,
}

thread_local!(static MONSTER_ID: Cell<usize> = Cell::new(0));

impl Monster {
    fn new(health: u8) -> Monster {
        MONSTER_ID.with(|thread_id| {
            let id = thread_id.get();
            thread_id.set(id + 1);
            Monster { id, health }
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let gnome = Monster::new(41);
    let troll = Monster::new(42);

    println!("gnome {:?}", gnome);
    println!("troll {:?}", troll);
}
```

If you do want something that works better with multiple threads, check out [bluss' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32936288/155423), which shows how to use an atomic variable.

Comment: I think you need to use wrapping_add because the + might panic. In atomicusize fetch_add they wrap

Comment: @Cecile To solve this problem in real life, I'd likely use `checked_add` and panic when wraparound occurs. If your **unique** ID wraps around and you start assigning the same ID to two instances, you will probably be very unhappy.

Answer (score 23):

Atomic variables can live in statics, so you can use it relatively straightforwardly (the downside is that you have global state).

Example code: [(playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ce3f2b51c1cd07a09e39f00e74d260a0)

```
use std::{
    sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering},
    thread,
};

static OBJECT_COUNTER: AtomicUsize = AtomicUsize::new(0);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Object(usize);

impl Object {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Object(OBJECT_COUNTER.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let threads = (0..10)
        .map(|_| thread::spawn(|| Object::new()))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    for t in threads {
        println!("{:?}", t.join().unwrap());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you suggest how to assert the ids are in fact unique without checking "by hand" the printed output ?