# Usage of a mutable global variable in a Rust module

Tags: rust

I have the module `string_queue`:

```
use crossbeam_utils::thread;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

pub struct MyText {
    my_text: Arc<Mutex<Vec<String>>>,
}

pub trait MyTextOptions {
    fn new() -> MyText;
    fn add(&self, t: &str);
    fn get(&self) -> String;
}

impl MyTextOptions for MyText {
    fn new() -> MyText {
        unimplemented!();
    }

    fn add(&self, text: &str) {
        unimplemented!();
    }

    fn get(&self) -> String {
        unimplemented!();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to declare a mutable variable in that module that corresponds to the defined `my_text` type in `pub struct MyText`, lives for the whole application execution time and can be used as an input variable in the defined `impl MyTextOptions for MyText` functions?

Basically, I'm looking for something similar to the usage of `self.__l = []` in this Python code, without using RustPython or similar Python + Rust hybrids.

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__l = []

    def add(self, t):
        self.__l += [t]

    def get(self):
        t = self.__l[0]
        self.__l = self.__l[1:]
        return t
```

Comment: See also [Generate sequential IDs for each instance of a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32935808/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster Thank you for the references, I didn’t find them so far.